# Proof by induction of a sum - how can I complete the proof?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove by induction that for each positive integer n

$$1+\frac{1}{2^r}+\frac{1}{3^r}+...+\frac{1}{(2^n-1)^r} \leq \frac{1-(\frac{1}{2})^{(r-1)n}}{1-(\frac{1}{2})^{(r-1)}}$$ with $(r \neq 1)$

Base step: for $n=1$ the inequality is $1\leq1$ which is correct.

Inductive step:

For the inductive step, first note that for k+1 we have on the left side of the inequality

$1+\frac{1}{2^r}+\frac{1}{3^r}+...+\frac{1}{(2^k-1)^r}+(\frac{1}{(2^k)^r}+\frac{1}{(2^k+1)^r}+...+\frac{1}{(2^{k+1}-1)^r})$

The parentheses contain $2^k-1$ terms and each term is less than $\frac{1}{(2^k)^r}$, so the sum of all terms in the parentheses is no more than $\frac{2^k-1}{(2^k)^r} \leq \frac{2^k}{(2^k)^r}=\frac{1}{2^{(r-1)k}}$.

Now, looking at the right side of the inequality, we see that $\frac{1-(\frac{1}{2})^{(r-1)(k+1)}}{1-(\frac{1}{2})^{(r-1)}}-\frac{1-(\frac{1}{2})^{(r-1)k}}{1-(\frac{1}{2})^{(r-1)}}=\frac{1}{2^{(r-1)k}}$

So $1+\frac{1}{2^r}+\frac{1}{3^r}+...+\frac{1}{(2^k-1)^r}+(\frac{1}{(2^k)^r}+\frac{1}{(2^k+1)^r}+...+\frac{1}{(2^{k+1}-1)^r}) \leq \frac{1-(\frac{1}{2})^{(r-1)k}}{1-(\frac{1}{2})^{(r-1)}}+\frac{1}{2^{(r-1)k}}= \frac{1-(\frac{1}{2})^{(r-1)(k+1)}}{1-(\frac{1}{2})^{(r-1)}}$ which is what we want.

Is this correct? Specifically, does the inequality hold for all values of r? If yes, how can I make this proof more clear?

Comment: Looks fine to me. 

(Off-topic) I also notice that $\frac{1-(\frac{1}{2})^{(r-1)n}}{1-(\frac{1}{2})^{(r-1)}}$ is actually a sum of $n$ terms of geometric progression with first term $1$ and common ratio $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{r-1}$.

Comment: "The parentheses contain $2^k-1$ terms" No, the number of the terms is given by $(2^{k+1}-1)-2^{k}+1=2^k$.